# Using the Web Audio API to analyze a song without playing

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have done some work with the web audio api and the `AnalyzerNode` class. However, `AnalyzerNode` only works when the audio element is playing. I would like to be able to get the same values that `getByteFrequencyData` returns for a certain point in the audio (or even for every n ms), but without playing the sound itself. I am working in electron, so if there is a Node.js solution to this problem, that would work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no official way of doing this with the Web Audio API. The `AnalyserNode` is only meant to return realtime data. Which means it returns whatever it currently has in its buffer. That is why it's difficult to control it precisely since there is no way to know exactly at which point in time that data was sampled when using a realtime `AudioContext`.

But there is a workaround. When using an `OfflineAudioContext` things are more deterministic. You can call `suspend()` to stop the rendering of an `OfflineAudioContext` at a certain point in time. When stopping it you know for sure which audio data was sampled at last by the `AnalyserNode`.

However you can only suspend an `OfflineAudioContext` after a full render quantum. For now ([web-audio-api#2450](https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/2450)) that means it can only be stopped every 128 samples.

Here is a example of how this can be done which assumes there is an AudioBuffer available called `buffer`.

```
const { length, sampleRate } = buffer;
const offlineAudioContext = new OfflineAudioContext({ length, sampleRate });
const audioBufferSourceNode = new AudioBufferSourceNode(offlineAudioContext, { buffer });
const analyserNode = new AnalyserNode(offlineAudioContext);

audioBufferSourceNode.connect(analyserNode);
audioBufferSourceNode.start();

const renderQuantumInSeconds = 128 / sampleRate;
const durationInSeconds = length / sampleRate;
const byteFrequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyserNode.frequencyBinCount);

const analyze = (index) => {
    const suspendTime = renderQuantumInSeconds * index;

    if (suspendTime < durationInSeconds) {
        offlineAudioContext.suspend(suspendTime).then(() => {
            analyserNode.getByteFrequencyData(byteFrequencyData);

            // do something with byteFrequencyData in here ...

            analyze(index + 1);
        });
    }

    if (index === 1) {
        offlineAudioContext.startRendering();
    } else {
        offlineAudioContext.resume();
    }
};

analyze(1);
```

Comment: You are amazing. One question, though: is there a way to be more precise? Or is 128 fixed? Oh, and also is this instant, or does the context have to play for the entire duration before this can be used?

Comment: Thanks. The processing is as fast as the browser can crunch the numbers. It should definitely be faster than doing it in realtime. The so called render quantum is currently fixed at 128 samples. But as discussed in the spec issue linked above it might get configurable in the future.